# imagejpeg() php return junk values

Tags: php, jquery, html

My jQuery Ajax code is:

```
<div class="page_rank">
 <form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" method="post">
 <span class="my_up_text">ENTER THE WEBSITE TO CHECK GOOGLE PAGE RANK:</span>
 <br /><br />
 <input type="text" name="my_site"/></div><div class="p_ity"><input type="submit" class="btn" value="PAGE RANK" /> </form></div><div id="my_pass"></div>

<script>
  function sub_form()
  {
      document.forms["searchForm"].submit();
  }

  $(function () {
    $('form#searchForm').on('submit', function(e) {
                    $( ".p_ity" ).hide();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'check-google-page-rank.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#my_pass').html(data);

            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});     
</script>
```

My php code is:

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
require('./get_page_rank.php');
$url=$_POST['my_site'];
//echo $url;
$pr = new PR();
//$rank= $pr->get_google_pagerank($url);
$rank=$pr->get_google_pagerank($url);

  // Create Image From Existing File
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('./images/page-rank/G.jpg');
if($jpg_image)
{
  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 0, 0, 0);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = './images/page-rank/Helvetica.TTF';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = $rank;

  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 85, 0, 305, 100, $white, $font_path, $text);

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image,NULL,100);

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
}
?>
```

It works perfectly if I execute the PHP separately with manual input so I think the problem is with jQuery `html()` function. I am sure the image is not corrupted and I am using utf-8 encoding and I also tried `base64_encode(imagejpeg())` but got the same output.

OUTPUT:

```
��*����D\�@��梸�����[[h� ��0 s��('�y\�ӎ+��_�P 7��){�i�i��ĽOH�
_��:�� VV���y�x���o~�Eh��R��U�1�C����|�~,�ѿ
��7׼c��|S�����W�:�g��� ����K�z��A��D .͓�<�n��F� d�Qƹ̸{%�*֣�2�q7c�9UJ�0s��w�ߞ>ҥX��UaQG��w�bq8��
```

Comment: you should save the contents of the image to a file, and have your PHP return an `<img>` tag with src set to url of file in stead of echoing the contents of the image and remove the `base64_encode()` function call. (You can leave the `imagedestroy()` though. And remove the `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` call

Comment: @nl-x I am not echoing the contents that line is commented in my code because imagejpeg() renders the image to the browser.

Comment: 'renders the image to the browser' is what I meant with 'echoing the contents of the image'. You don't want that. Save it to a file, and echo `<img src='that_file.jpg' />`. So that image tag will be put in your HTML by ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imagejpeg()` outputs the image to browser directly, so the response is not the html content you could use with `.html()`, you don't have to use ajax in this case, the url should be used as the `src` of an image tag.

You could do like below:

```
$(function () {
    $('form#searchForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        $( ".p_ity" ).hide();
        $('<img />').attr('src', 'check-google-page-rank.php?my_site='+ encodeURIComponent($('[name= "my_site"]').val())).load(function() {
          $(this).appendTo('#my_pass');
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

And change `$url=$_POST['my_site'];` to `$url=$_GET['my_site'];`.

Comment: Thanks but can I do this via POST method or not?

Comment: @user1613360 No. That's why I didn't suggest this solution

Comment: @user1613360 No, because you used as `src` of an image, which could only append query string, so only via GET.

Comment: But actually there is very little change for you to change POST to GET

Answer (score 0):

In your php handler, write your image in a file;

```
$imgFolderPAth = "/path/to/img/";
imagejpeg($jpg_image,$imgFolderPAth . "image.jpg",100);
echo $imgFolderPAth . "image.jpg";
```

and in your js;

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'check-google-page-rank.php',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        $('#my_pass').html('<img src="' + data + '"/>');

    }
});
```

Or alternatively you can use;

```
imagejpeg($jpg_image,NULL,100);
$rawImageBytes = ob_get_clean();

echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode( $rawImageBytes ) . "' />";
```

and in your js, you can use as it is